# There is a way to automaticaly inject a model into a controller in laravel, without using the Illuminate\Http\Request?

Tags: laravel, controller, request

I would like to now if there is some method I can use to directily inject a model in a controller in Laravel, without using the Illuminate\Http\Request, something like Springboot in Java.

I have something like:

```
public function update(Request $request){
    $example = new Example();
    $example->param1 = $request->input('param1');
    $example->param2 = $request->input('param2');
    $example->save();
}
```

I would like to know if I can have something like this:

```
public function update(Example $example)
```

And if Laravel have some kind of support to autommaticaly get the Example with the data set, without the need to manipulate de Request.

Comment: You have to name route parameter example, those in route and action have to match. In other words to make it work that way your route parameter has to be named `/{example}`. Also don't forget $request object argument `update(Request $request, Example $example)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function update(Example $example)
```

With this, you can get data set if the `$example` is equal to the id of `Example` model in your database. Laravel will return full dataset only if `$example` is equal to `id`, otherwise, you need to make `::where` search on model